# How to prevent access to a directory with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

How do I prevent access to a given directory ? Here is the structure of my website :

```
config.php
.htaccess
classes/
|----lib/
|    |----...
|----classes.php
webroot/
|----index.php
|----ctrl/
|    |----...
|----pages/
|    |----...
|----style/
     |----...
```

The `DocumentRoot` is `webroot`. I want to prohibit access to the following folders : `ctrl`, `pages`, `style`. But the files stored in these folders still have to be available to be included in the `index.php` file.

In other words, there is an `index.php` file. Its role is to call (include) all the necessary files from `pages/`, ... The users can load `index.php` from their browser but they cannot access the other files alone.

I wrote this code is a `.htaccess` file but it doesn't do anything :

```
deny from all
<Files webroot/index.php>
allow from all
</Files>
```

This `.htaccess` file is located at the root folder for my project (before `webroot/`). What I try to do here is to deny access to every directory and files in the project except for the main `index.php` file.

What is it not working ? What went wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'included' w/ php i assume? not with `<link>`

Comment: With both actually. The files in the `style` directory are .css files, fonts, ... so they are include with <link>. The other files are included with php (`include()`)

Comment: Which version of Apache? For 2.4 it should be `Require all denied` instead

Comment: The version I use is version 2.4.18. So instead of `deny from all` I should use `Require all denied` ?

Comment: Authorization syntax changed completely from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. First of all, I had to activate `.htaccess` files in my `httpd.conf` file. Then I wrote this in my `.htaccess` :

```
<Files webroot/pages>
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files webroot/style>
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to prevent people list files in your webroot?
If so, you can add the following option in your htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. My application works this way : there is an `index.php` file and some other files. Users can access `index.php` and `index.php` includes the necessary files to display a webpage. But for security reasons, these other files mustn't be accessed independently. They can only be included in `index.php`. Maybe I wasn't very clear on that, I will update my question.